# Creating an auto-slider in android with images and videos?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-sliding

I'm new to android and I want to make an app which will be displaying images automatically at a given interval. This app will not only contain images but videos also, and it should slide through all of these (images and videos), and when somebody clicks anywhere on the window a new activity should start.
Any help on how can I do this? I have read all the flipper or pager commands on Stack Overflow itself, but I'm unable to achieve this. Can anyone help me?
Also the admin should be able to update and modify the image/videos it will be displaying? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create viewpager (if want to create custom view pager follow this link https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator) and provide id to each item, on create view change the item of the view, increase item number and again at last number decrease( for this you can use this link https://github.com/Trinea/android-auto-scroll-view-pager) on each item click get the data from the list and perform your own task.